# Bee swarm plot with SHAP values for Random forest

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, shap

I am trying to visualize the results for SHAP values using a random forest before.

I am working in this piece of code:

```
# Load necessary libraries
library(randomForest)
library(DALEX)
library(beeswarm)

data <- turismo_rf

# Split the data into features and target
features <- data[, -which(names(data) %in% "Clus.1")]
target <- data$Clus.1

# Train a random forest model
rf_model <- randomForest(features, target)

# Create an explainer object
explainer <- DALEX::explain(rf_model, data = features, y = target)

# Compute SHAP values
shapley_values <- DALEX::predict_parts(explainer, new_observation = features)

# Plot bee swarm
beeswarm(shapley_values$shap_1)
```

The problem is that I have tried using `beeswarm package`

but I always get this error:

```
beeswarm(shapley_values$shap_1)
Error in rep(nms, sapply(x, length)) : invalid 'times' argument
```

Can you please suggest me what is wrong about the beeswarm?

[Output I want to do](https://imgur.com/pFGolIs)

[And this is the output I get](https://imgur.com/oAgi3GV) if I use just `plot(shapley_values)`

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: @Quinten I added the output, can you check please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{DALEX} does not support plotting/working with SHAP values of *multiple* observations. Plotting SHAP beeswarm plots is easy with {shapviz}. Calculating SHAP values can done by different packages, e.g., {kernelshap}, {fastshap}, or {treeshap}.

Note that random forests are one of the worst for SHAP, because trees are deep and predictions are very slow.

#### Kernel SHAP or permutation SHAP

```r
library(randomForest)
library(kernelshap)  # or library(treeshap)
library(shapviz)

fit <- randomForest(Sepal.Length ~ ., data = iris)

xvars <- setdiff(colnames(iris), "Sepal.Length")

# Or kernelshap() if length(xvars) is >10. Subsample bg_X to 100-500 rows
shap_values <- permshap(fit, X = iris, bg_X = iris, feature_names = xvars)
shap_values <- shapviz(shap_values)
sv_importance(shap_values, kind = "bee")
```

[image]

Comment: Just the excellent answer I was searching for. I checked your profile and our interests in research align perfectly. Can you please accept the invitation I send to you in LinkedIn?